# How to post an image to Instagram, after taken the access_token through my iOS app?

Tags: ios, instagram, access-token

I used the Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication as described in http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ and I receive the access_token. How can I use this to post a photo in the user's Instagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram does not allow posting photos from anywhere but their own mobile apps. Third party developers do not have access to this API. However, since you are on iOS you can use their iOS hooks to open Instagram to the share screen with a photo from your app as described on `http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/` under the `Document Interaction` section.